# ES6 Promises: Promise status not as I expect

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand Es6 Promisss in depth. I have the next code:

```
function getValues(){
    return Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}

getValues().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

My console output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

I would expect that after the data being printed the promise state would be `resolved`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know which promise you are looking at - where is it logged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `then()` returns a Promise. If you print `getVaules()`, you can see the status is `resolved`, which is what you expect to see.
[image]